# Difference between logger and __name__ in logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

According to the official logging [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html),

> ```
> logging.getLogger([name])
> ```
>
> Return a logger with the specified name or, if no name is specified, return a logger which is the root logger of the hierarchy. If specified, the name is typically a dot-separated hierarchical name like “a”, “a.b” or “a.b.c.d”. Choice of these names is entirely up to the developer who is using logging.

What is the difference between the name we are passing as argument and the name of the object we are actually catching the logger into?

ie difference between `logger` and `__name__` in the statement

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between the name we are passing as argument and the name of the object we are actually catching the logger into?

That's absolutely different things:

1. `logger` in your case is the way to access logger object later in your code (most probably, in scope of single file). `logger` acts as local variable pointing to logger object. You can, actually, call your `.log` with

   ```
   getLogger(__name__).info('My data')
   ```

   but it's just less practical that referencing it by variable name
2. `__name__` is derived name of current module, normally this will be dotted path like `project.module.submodule` — this can be any string that makes sense to you. `__name__` makes a lot of sense usually, so it became sort of convention

Answer (score 1):

One is just a reference - `logger`, what we call a variable and has nothing to do with the logging process. You could call it `babapaloopa` and that would not make any difference at all, except make your program cooler when referencing the logging object (though something could be said about good design here). I would stress this **is not the name of the object**, just the name of a variable that happens to reference the object - you could:

```
another_reference = logger
```

and now both `another_reference` and `logger` are both pointing to the same logging object, and clearly the variable name is unrelated to the object. Objects do have ids, but that is not something you should tamper with usually.

The `name` argument will become the actual name associated with the logger, a property of the logger object itself, not just a name of a reference to it - likely stored in the initialization of the object. The fact you use `__name__` which is a special string, or some other string is just a detail, the point is this will be the name of the logger from a programming viewpoint.

```
logger.name
```

will hold this name after the logger is defined (assuming `logger` is reference to said logging object of course).